# How to compile sticky state plugin for Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ecmascript-5

I need the Sticky States feature for my project.
I'm using **UI Router 1.0.0-rc.1** so i can't use the ui-router-extras library (that was designed for 0.xxx)

Recently the author ported that feature for the 1.xx router
https://github.com/ui-router/sticky-states

This release comes only with .ts sources.
My project is written in *plain* ES5 js, so i tried to build myself the final js to be used in browser with `<script src="..." type="text/javascript">`

I have `npm install` all dependancies and then `npm run build`

What i got are two folders '`lib`' and '`lib-esm`' that contains each more than one js files that i don't understand how to reference them from .html file (files are `index.js` & `stickyStates.js`)

Also tried to run `webpack` but what i get is a huge file with more than 8K lines of code (probabile also ui-router get bundled within..)

**NOTE:** Author has already been asked for that by someone but he didn't provided a solution yet:
https://github.com/ui-router/sticky-states/issues/4

Thank you very much

Comment: did you get this sorted?